# chess UI in android

Tags: android

I want to create simple UI for chess game in Android.
I want to adjust the screen to all kinds of mobiles.
I make a TableLayout with Table Row , each Row contain 8 Linear Layout that contain the View 
for the players , my problem is that i make the width and the height of each linear layout in specific size (40 dp width and height), what is the best teqhniques to make the width and height right , here is the layout in xml file i described one row here ,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


-<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="120dp" android:layout_width="120dp" android:background="@android:color/white">

<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_marginTop="24dp" android:layout_marginLeft="33dp" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>


-<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow0" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/n00" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:background="@android:color/white" android:orientation="horizontal"/>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/n01" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:orientation="horizontal"> </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/n02" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:background="@android:color/white" android:orientation="horizontal"/>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/n03" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:orientation="horizontal"> </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/n04" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:background="@android:color/white" android:orientation="horizontal"/>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/n05" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:orientation="horizontal"> </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/n06" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:background="@android:color/white" android:orientation="horizontal"/>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/n07" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:orientation="horizontal"> </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were developing a chess UI, I would not use frame layouts, but look into using a `SurfaceView`, and drawing onto a canvas.

Every View has a canvas, which is the what is actually drawn to the screen. If you create your own, you will be able to get much better control and render speeds, and you can just create the checkerboard with a simple look in your Java Code.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest a different way to create your chess layout?

Consider a *vertical* LinearLayout (this will make your rows) containing *horizontal* linear  (your columns). And then in each horizontal LinearLayout, have eight Buttons/ImageButtons. Here's an [open source implementation](http://code.google.com/p/cuckoochess/source/browse/trunk/DroidFish/res/layout/main_left_handed.xml) of such a layout.

Now the question is how to correctly space these out (this should be applicable to your orignal layout if you want to keep it). There are two main ways we could do this:

1. Make the chess board fit on the screen, no scrolling needed.
2. Make the chess board a minimum width/height, scrolling may be necessary.

To accomplish the former, your outer layout should have `match_parent` for both width and height. Your inner layouts should `match_parent` for the width and `wrap_content` for height. Then your individual cells should have a `weight` attribute of 1. There are limitations to this approach, like how you won't be able to have any views to the side of the chess board (above and below should have space though).

To accomplish the latter (**this is what you were asking for**), the width and height attributes of your outer and inner layouts should be `wrap_content`. I also suggest you embed your structure in a ScrollView in case it expands past the screen.